# get bean data in javascript array

Tags: java, javascript, jsf-2, jstl, javabeans

I am making the image slider where I want to pull the image name from server.

For dynamic, below is what I have.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    var firstreel=new reelslideshow({
        wrapperid: "myreel", //ID of blank DIV on page to house Slideshow
        dimensions: [800, 600], //width/height of gallery in pixels. Should reflect dimensions of largest image
        imagearray: [
            ["http://www.almaktab.com/iPhoneApp/gallery/image001.jpg"], //["image_path", "optional_link", "optional_target"]
            ["http://www.almaktab.com/iPhoneApp/gallery/image002.jpg", "http://www.almaktab.com/iPhoneApp/gallery/image002.jpg", "_new"],
            ["http://www.almaktab.com/iPhoneApp/gallery/image003.jpg"],
            ["http://www.almaktab.com/iPhoneApp/gallery/image004.jpg"] 
            //-no trailing comma after very last image element!
        ],
        displaymode: {type:'auto', pause:4000, cycles:2, pauseonmouseover:true},
        orientation: "h", //Valid values: "h" or "v"
        persist: true, //remember last viewed slide and recall within same session?
        slideduration: 300 //transition duration (milliseconds)
    })

</script>
```

Now I want to replace `imagearray` with the image names that I have on database.

Hence what I did is below.

```
xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"

<h:body>
    <f:metadata>
        // pulling image names
        <f:event type="preRenderView" listener="#{FullScopeBens.pullMyImageNames()}"/>
    </f:metadata>

<script type="text/javascript">
    alert('perfect = ');

    var data = {
            <c:forEach items="${FullScopeBens.myDealsList}" var="ctag" varStatus="loop">
            '${ctag.imagePath}': '${ctag.imagePath}${!loop.last ? ',' : ''}
            </c:forEach>
        };
    alert('perfect = ' + data);
</script>
```

and planned to replace `imagearray:...` to `imagearray:data`.

But its not working.

When I print

```
<c:forEach items="#{FullScopeBens.myDealsList}" var="item">
    ${item.id}==${item.title}
</c:forEach>
```

I get proper id and title for that image.

Any idea how can I get image path in javascript.

[Reference for above loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4506816/is-possible-javascript-extract-value-from-cforeach-tag)

Even I tried below link. But still not working.

https://community.jboss.org/thread/160332

(look for `3. Dec 23, 2010 8:31 AM (in response to Eswara MoorthyNEC)`)

---

### Answer

Below link helped me for answer.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/4143187/1066828

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below link helped me for answer.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/4143187/1066828

So what I was doing is assigning the bean data to textfield and through javascript I am getting the data from textfield and using that in array.